# How to create cover flow with different view controllers?

Tags: iphone, ipad, tiles, carousel, coverflow

I want to show view controllers's view as images in tiles. But how to get the images of all view controllers before loading those view controllers. Suggest me some solution. I was looking through the link [Flowcover](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m)

**EDIT**

But My views have graphs, which is drawn from a dynamic content(fetched from web service). How could I take a screenshot without loading the view?  If not, can u suggest me some other solution to display in 'tiles'.

Answer (score 2):

Use view controller as a image is not possible but you can take diagrammatically screen shot of ur view and use it in cover flow. i also used this trick and work as a charm.

Thx

Comment: can you explain diagrammatically screen shot?

Comment: Hi, You can take ur view screen shot using http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/27/1188/ and add this and save this image in ur application folder (replace previous image) and it works fine for you. thx

Comment: thanks for ur answer. But My views have graphs, which is drawn from a dynamic content. How could I take a screenshot without loading the view? If not, can u suggest me some other solution to display in 'tiles'..

Comment: First you can take screen shot and add these to bundle. and after this when your drawing is  complete on your view then again take screen shot and replace previous one.so next time you will see ur latest screen. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to write the cover flow in OpenGL and build textures using the viewController views. When each view controller comes to the front, you can draw its view over the top of your OpenGL scene so that the user can interact with it. When the user moves the coverflow again, this UIView is hidden and they will once again be looking at a texture 'snapshot' of the viewController.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. But My views have graphs, which is drawn from a dynamic content. how could i make a texture for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can load your controls or graphs in a view which is already hidden. then take a screen screen shot in program and use that image for texture drawing.